# How to convert data in text file to data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have data in a text file where each row have one value and total number of columns is 4 (in this case first four rows = first column in data frame):

```
#this is the raw data:
test1
100
95
red
test2
50
70
blue
test3
66
88.8
yellow
```

Desired output:

[image]

Comment: if you read it in as a single column/vector you could use `matrix(x, ncol = 4)` to convert it into a 4 column table

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option:

```
df <- read.table(text = "test1
                 100
                 95
                 red
                 test2
                 50
                 70
                 blue
                 test3
                 66
                 88.8
                 yellow", header = FALSE)
as.data.frame(matrix(df$V1, ncol = 4, byrow = TRUE))
# output
     V1  V2   V3     V4
1 test1 100   95    red
2 test2  50   70   blue
3 test3  66 88.8 yellow
```

Comment: That works, but note that all columns will be factors, and to convert `V2` and `V3` to numeric you need to first convert to character, then numeric.

Comment: To fix this you can do `df <- as.data.frame(matrix(df$V1, ncol = 4, byrow = TRUE), stringsAsFactors = F);
df[2:3] <- lapply(df[2:3], as.numeric)`

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this by doing the following:

```
test.file <- read.delim(file.choose(), sep = "\n", header = FALSE)
as.data.frame(matrix(test.file$V1, ncol = 4, byrow = T))
```

If you are using RStudio `file.choose()` will open a dialog that allows you to select your text file.